# How do I use DB SELECT to return only CHOSEN categories in a specific group while in an entries tag?

Tags: categories, query

I am working in a channel entries tag. I want to return an array of category names that are selected in the entry, if they are in group_id 4. This is what I have so far...  however, it is returning **all** my categories in group_id 4 not just the ones selected in that entry.

```
$this->EE =& get_instance();
$res = $this->EE->db->select('cat_name')->where('group_id', 4)->get('categories')->result_array();
    foreach ($res as $r)
    {
        $entryregionArr[] = $r['cat_name'];
    }
    if (in_array($_GET['region'], $entryregionArr)) {
        echo "Africa is in this array";
    }

   print_r($res);
```

I am then going to see if my $_Get value is in the array. Right now with all the categories in group_id 4 returning, Africa is always in the array. so it returns everytime.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have JOIN statement for it. Like:

```
$this->EE =& get_instance();
$entry_id = '[FETCH ENTRY ID]';
$res = $this->EE->db->select('c.cat_name')
                ->from('categories c')
                ->join('category_posts cp', 'cp.cat_id = c.cat_id')
                ->join('channel_titles ct', 'c.entry_id = cp.entry_id')
                ->where('c.group_id', 4)
                ->where('ct.entry_id', $entry_id)
                ->result_array();
```

I hope, it would help you.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why the page is loading as straight up code when I place this code into it. I should place it between my php open and close tags, correct? Or do I need to do anything with the FETCH ENTRY ID?